# Custom stdout and stdin for writing and reading data in same module - Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying the following in python.

Method 1 writes output to a custom stdout (StringIO) that method 2 reads from. The code goes like this

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

stringIOObj = StringIO()
default_stdout = sys.stdout
default_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdout = stringIOObj
sys.stdin = stringIOObj

def method1_write():
      sys.stdout.write("Hello World\n")
      sys.stdout.write("\n") #End of line
      sys.stdout.flush()

def method2_read():
      sys.stdout = default_stdout 
      for line in sys.stdin:
            print line

if __name__ == "__main__":
      method1_write()
      method2_read()
      sys.stdin = default_stdin
```

The goal is for two methods to communicate through custom stdout and stdin. I could solve this through other ways, but I am trying to eliminate few command line piping by using the writer and reader methods in the same module.

In this case, there is no output written

```
>>> 
>>>
```

Not sure what's wrong with this approach when there is no error thrown as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from you using the same buffer. After you've written to it, the file position is at the end, so you are reading nothing! So, at some point before you read, you have to `seek(0)`. This works:

```
def method1_write():
      sys.stdout.write("Hello World\n")
      sys.stdout.write("\n") #End of line
      sys.stdout.flush()
      sys.stdout.seek(0)
```

In any event, you should definitely be using some for of context managers to achieve this. Check out this question on CodeReview:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98393/context-managers-that-also-deal-with-sys-stdin-and-sys-stdout

Comment: This is cleaner. I will use Context Managers for these problems.

Comment: @sysuser If you use Python 3 the `print` function takes a `file` keyword argument that let's you write to that file with print. You can obtain that function by using `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Through more experimentation, found a quick solution. The following works.

```
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO

stringIOObj = StringIO()
default_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = stringIOObj

def method1_write():
      sys.stdout.write("Hello World")
      sys.stdout.flush()

def method2_read():
      sys.stdout = default_stdout
      customStdIn = StringIO(stringIOObj.getvalue())
      for line in customStdIn:
            print line

if __name__ == "__main__":
      method1_write()
      method2_read()
```

This prints what I wanted.

```
>>> 
Hello World
>>>
```

Not sure why the same StringIO object can't be used for both input and output.